# Redmine workflows doesn't work

Tags: redmine

I have already working Redmine workflows and Roles. I try to change workflow for a certain role, but changes doesn't make any sense. I have the same list of statuses as before workflow update. Redmine version is 3.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you John for answer. Yes they work for users with out admin permissions. But for admins workflow change doesn't make sense.